# How can I use Firebase products in cocos2d-js

Tags: firebase, cocos2d-js

Cloud Firestore doesn't have a c++ library, so I cannot use it with cocos2d-cpp. I decided to use cocos2d-js instead and there are web libraries for most of Firebase products. Now, how can I use Firebase APIs in my cocos2d-js project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase plugin](https://docs.sdkbox.com/en/plugins/firebase/v3-js/) for SDKBOX